# Navigation error - This navigation graph is not referenced to any layout files?

Tags: android, android-navigation

I am trying to apply `navigation` feature to my project.

And I have this error:

```
This navigation graph is not referenced to any layout files(expected to find it in at least one layout file with a NavHostFragment with app:navGraph="@navigation/@navigation" attribute
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:label="fragment_init"
    app:startDestination="@id/initFragment"
    >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/initFragment"
        android:label="fragment_init"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_init">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_initFragment_to_authenticationFragment5"
            app:destination="@id/authenticationFragment"
            />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_initFragment_to_settingFragment3"
            app:destination="@id/settingFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/authenticationFragment"
        android:name="com.example.AuthenticationFragment"
        android:label="fragment_authentication"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_authentication" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingFragment"
        android:name="com.example.view.main.fragment.SettingFragment"
        android:label="SettingFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_setting" />
</navigation>
```

I added that attribute here and there (navigation and fragments ). And also, the layout files in layout folder which are used in navigation.xml. But didn't work.

This is `activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:tint="#555"
    tools:context=come.example.view.main.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_flame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: use of fragmentcontainerview also give above result

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You haven't set up for your `<fragment>` correctly - every `<fragment>` needs an `android:name` pointing to the Fragment class it is loading. In the case of Navigation, it must reference the `androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment` as per the [Getting Start documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#add-navhostfragment):

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"/>
```

Once you actually tie your navigation graph to a `NavHostFragment`, the error will go away.

Comment: I have added         android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
and I'm still getting the exact same error

Comment: I noticed that even though I have app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" added to my fragment as described in the guide, the property app:navGraph is actually not there. I can write it, but it will never appear in autocomplete - meaning it is useless even if its there...

Comment: @iamhanniballake `<fragmentcontainerview/>` also give's the above error so i am currently avoiding to use fragmentcontainerview.What is solution to that?

Comment: I had this issue in Android Studio 4.1 and 4.2 Previews. Reverted to Android Studio 4.0 Stable and everything works.

Answer (score 6):

If the accepted answer does not work initially, try "Make Project". Worked for me with `<fragment/>`

Answer (score 1):

If other solutions haven't exactly worked, this worked for me, hopefully helps someone else as well

Especially if you work with Kotlin, check to see whether your dependencies have the same Kotlin versions working (Also anything that has an update or notification or something), then rebuild/sync, takes a bit to load, and at least for me seems to be working fine.

*If didn't work try invalidate catch/restart, who knows

Answer (score 0):

if you still get the error after applying what's in the accepted answer then try this - I had the same error, but my activity was working. The error disappeared after I changed the dependencies from android to androidx

```
nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha03"
```

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"
```

I also use `class` rather than `android:name` in the xml layout

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
    class="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

Answer (score 0):

Though late hope someone will get benefit. I had the same issue. Used

```
android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment" 
app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation"
```

. But  was still showing same error. Then finally i solved my issue by looking at build.gradle file.

first my gradle file was like this:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0-beta01"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0-beta01"
```

then I have added this extra dependency with those dependencies which solved the issue:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.3.0-beta01"
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause for this, at least in my case, was having layout files for portrait and landscape mode, and forgetting to add the `androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment` view to both of them. Adding the block to the `layout-land/your_activity_layout.xml` made the graph to show properly in Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Just clean your project Build-> Clean Project